# Slack Events api / how to recieve message from Slack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, slack, slack-api

I've a socket.io connected server on localhost:8080 and try to recieve message from Slack to display on the client side on React app.

```
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");
var app = express();
const { App } = require("@slack/bolt");

const appBolt = new App({
  token: "xoxb-***",
  appToken:
    "xapp-1-***",
  socketMode: true,
});

server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log("server is running on port 8080");
  appBolt.start(process.env.PORT || 8080);
});

io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("socket.id: ", socket.id);
  socket.on("SEND_MESSAGE", function (data) {
    io.emit("RECEIVE_MESSAGE", data);
  });
```

And client side on React

```
const socket = io("localhost:8080");
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const addMessage = (data) => {
    setMessages([...messages, data]);
  };

  socket.on("RECEIVE_MESSAGE", (data) => {
    console.log("MESSAGE_RECIEVED", data);
    addMessage(data);
  });
}
```

Could you tell me please, how to combine socket.io with Slack events api to send data?
In **event** I recieve message from Slack.

```
appBolt.event('message', ({ event, say }) => {  
    say(`Hello world, <@${event.user}>!`);
    return event;
});
```

[My Slack app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHylV.png)
[My Socket mode settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywm2O.png)

Comment: My first question would be have you got socket mode enabled and interactive events enabled via the Slack app configuration? I would go through this [tutorial](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started#next-steps) to check. It takes you through the implementation without socket.io

Comment: Dear @BradleyIW, thank you! Yes, I created Slack app and Socket mode enables with interactive events. I added in question body additional links with screenshots of my Slack app settings. So, now I can remove socket.io and use sockets without it?